# Adding arrays generated in for loop in Python

Tags: arrays, numpy, average

I have a for loop (100 passes) which generates a numpy array during each pass. Is there a way to add these 100 arrays (element wise) and then calculate the array which represents the average of these 100 arrays?

Comment: One option is to collect the arrays in a list, and make a multidimensional array from that.  Then it's easy to apply `np.mean` along the right axis.  But if all you need is the mean, you could sum at each step, e.g. `total += new_array`, and get the mean from that sum.

Comment: @ hpaulj -- Thank you!  The np.mean suggestion works well. I had not collected the arrays correctly as a list, so was caught up.  Now, it's resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for:

```
np.mean(arr, axis=0)
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
np.sum(arr, axis=0) / len(arr)
```

Here, `arr` is the array you created with the loop.

You can define `arr` as:

```
arr = []
for i in range(100):
    # create numpy array here and assign it to x
    arr.append(x)
```

Then you can do `np.mean` etc on `arr`.